# iOS Parse Chat App: Updating data from multiple pushes while in background/inactive.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm implementing an iOS chat app using Parse. Currently, most chat data is stored on the user's device.

When you send a push from one user to another, and the receiving user is on the app, the device will save the message along with its data (who it's from, when sent, etc). From there, if the receiving user is chatting with the sending user, their chat dialog will update. If they are still using the app, but not chatting with that user at the moment, a popup will display with the message.

This works great for when they are in the app.

But when they are outside of the app, a push will come through with the data (message, who sent it, when sent, etc), and a push notification will popup on the user's screen. But when they open up the app, I am not sure how to transfer that data from the push to the app's storage.

I guess I do understand how to do it (if there was only ONE push notification AND the user opened the app by tapping the push notification: there is a delegate method that seems to have a dictionary of the push notification's data).

However, in the case of there being multiple messages being sent before the user opens the app, and/or the user opens the app using the app icon (and not by opening the app from the notification), I am not sure how to access this data. It would seem like there would be some sort of way to get an array of dictionary objects, but I'm not sure.

I know I could implement a way to store the data on Parse, and then delete it when it has been downloaded, but if I don't have to do it that way, I wouldn't want to.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store the data in Parse and allow them to query all messages since they last checked.

I would suggest using a counter every time a message is saved, that way in the receiver you can check if that counter has only gone up by one compared to a local copy of the counter, which means you can just use the message in the push notification. If it has gone up by more than one then you know you have to ask Parse for the rest of the messages.

You can have Cloud Code that each participant in the chat calls to say what number they're up to... then you can delete anything with a value less than the lowest of all the participants. You could even integrate this logic into the `getMessagesSince(counterValue)` call.

Note that in this case you would also want a `gotMessageFromPush(counterValue)` to let the server know that you got a message via Push.